# Use jquery to mousedown on slider() so i can move slider without clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to slide yw0 until Credit_Amount reaches > 200 then i would like to make it so without letting go of mouse i will slide yw2? Is this possible? I have tried using mousedown and trigger without any avail. I am relatively new to Jquery so its possible i missed something. How do you see about adding this functionality?

My Live Code: http://dev4you.byethost15.com/Loan%20Calculator/

My First Slider:

```
jQuery('#yw0').slider({
        'range': 'max',
        'min': 0,
        'max': 130,
        'slide': function(event, ui) {

            $("#Credit_Amount").val(ui.value);

            $("#AmountsDiv").text(GetAmount(ui.value));

            GenerateAdditionalPrecents(ui.value);

            RefreshValues();

            if (parseInt($("#AmountsDiv").text()) > "195") {
                $("#tab2").addClass("selected");
                $("#loan").addClass("hide");
                $("#tab1").removeClass("selected");
                $("#loan2").removeClass("hide");
                $('#yw0').trigger('mouseup');

                $("#yw2 .ui-slider-handle").css('left', '23.0769230769231%');
                $("#yw2 .ui-slider-range").css('width', '76.9230769230769%');


            } else {
                $("#tab1").addClass("selected");
                $("#loan2").addClass("hide");
                $("#tab2").removeClass("selected");
                $("#loan").removeClass("hide");
            }

        },
        'value': 0
});
```

My Second Slider:

```
jQuery('#yw2').slider({
        'range': 'max',
        'min': 0,
        'max': 130,
        'slide': function(event, ui) {

            $("#Credit_Amount2").val(ui.value);

            $("#AmountsDiv2").text(GetAmount(ui.value));

            GenerateAdditionalPrecents2(ui.value);

            RefreshValues2();

        },
        'value': 0
});
```

Comment: I think this doesn't sound like a good idea.  Taking over the control of common controls, while the user is manipulating them ... it's tricky.  I can't image this working well on different browsers.  What if you leave the slider alone, but manipulate all the rest ?  Get the numbers of the other tab, highlight the tap head, ... At mouseUp you make it permanent.  Just an idea.

Comment: I know its out of the ordinary but all i want to do is pass the mousedown to the other slider really. Is it possible?